# Open record details in a panel within a Visualforce page

Tags: visualforce, controller, controller-extension, bootstrap

I have written a bootstrapped page that has a custom list view panel on the left side of the page and an output panel on the right side of the page. I have the left panel figured out where different list views are shown based on a dropdown. I'm better at front-end development than back-end logic. How can I write my code so that when I click on a record's name in the left panel the record will open in the right panel? Any sample code you could provide would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can place an iframe in the right panel and page in the iframe that takes record Id as the parameter.

When a record name is clicked in the left panel you can passe the record Id to the page in right Panel, which will then reload with all the required details for that record